# Merge two different array with different values

Tags: php, arrays, php-7

I have the following array like so

```
$foo = [
    a => 0,
    b => 0,
    c => 0,
    d => 0
];

$bar = [
    c => 3,
]
```

How can I merge $foo and $bar in such  a way that the output is like this

```
$foobar = [
    a => 0,
    b => 0,
    c => 3,
    d => 0
]
```

I have tried array_diff and array_intersect but didn't get any result.

Comment: Its time to try array_replace() :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [array-replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) function. The following snippet should work:

```
<?php
$foo = [
    a => 0,
    b => 0,
    c => 0,
    d => 0
];

$bar = [
    c => 3,
];

$merged = array_replace($foo, $bar);
print_r($merged);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [a] => 0 [b] => 0 [c] => 3 [d] => 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

array_replace_recursive($foo, $bar);

Answer (score 0):

```
$merge=array_merge($foo,$baar);


print_r($merge);
```

Output

```
[a] => 0 [b] => 0 [c] => 3 [d] => 0
```

Second parameter make overide to first parameter